# Android : loc : wrong sig ->cc411521

Tags: android, android-studio-arctic-fox

I am able to sync the gradle file successfully, But On running the code, getting the

```
loc: wrong sig ->cc411521
```

Not able to understand, What is this related to, There is no compile time error is showing in the project.

- I already tried with cleaning the project,
- Rebuilding the project,
- deleting the.idea folder
- deleting the .gradle folder
- deleting the .gradle from user/<user_name>/.gradle
- Invidate caches and restart

Nothing works for me.
Please suggest.

[image]

Comment: did you fix it?